# How to get response HTTP status from Karate Call? Getting response status as 204 but karate.log(result.response) is blank

Tags: karate

I'm calling a webservice through Karate API. When the service is executed, I am getting HTTP status 204 which is expected. However, when I log the response, I get blank.

Below is my webservice call, response and log output

```
    result = karate.call('ExecuteWebService.feature', [urlToExecute]);
    karate.log("Response is " + result.response); #Expecting that code displays HTTP status here
```

I know am getting proper response for call because my logs show below content

```
    HH.mm.ss.mil [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 
    1 < 204
    1 < Date: Fri, Rest of date portion
    1 < X-Application-Context: App Context Data
```

However karate.log doesn't display the status code. I need status code so I can assert the status against my expected values and thus pass/fail the test

```
    HH.mm.ss.mil [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 431
    HH.mm.ss.mil [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] 
    HH.mm.ss.mil [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - Response is
```

Can you advice on how to extract HTTP status from karate.call result so I can assert the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work,

```
* def status = result.responseStatus
```

similary you can also access `response`, `responseTime`, `responseHeaders`, `responseCookies`

Comment: one more thing you can access all the variables that you defined in you called feature as well.

Comment: print your 'result' variable to see all the data returned from your karate.call

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It printed something like com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@423c5404. So wasn't sure how to get data out of the ObjectMap. What you answered was something I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

204 response code means:

> The server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no
>   additional content to send in the response payload body

So, it is normal, that you don't have anything in response body.
In your case, I would verify only that status code is correct (according application specifications).

Comment: How do I get the status code from result? Currently karate.log() display blank for status code and not 204